# Issue with creating and inserting values into an object

Tags: c++, oop, vector

What I am trying to do here is create objects and store them in vectors, and assign values to those objects via a file by getting each line.

For Example:
I have a Player class with the values `name, classType, strength, endurance, and id`

Then through a text or cfg file I want to assign values to each of these variables and make an object out of them and then push them into a vector.

#### My Question:

How do you assign values from a text file into an object and then push that object into a vector?

#### The Issues:

I'm getting a whole ton  of error messages which I will put below.

#### What My Preferred Outcome is:

For the text written in the file to be created into an object and have that object be pushed into a vector.

Here is what I have tried below.

### Player.txt

```
example1 Scribe 3 6 1
example2 Cursed 3 3 2
example3 Thief 3 1 3
example4 Paladin 9 5 4
example5 Hobo 3 7 5
```

### DEPENDENCIES.h

```
#ifndef DEPENDENCIES_H
#define DEPENDENCIES_H
 std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, Player& player) {
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(str, line)) {
       std::stringstream lineStream(line);

       std::string name;
       std::string classType;
       int         strength;
       int         endurance;
       int         id;

       if (lineStream >> name >> classType >> strength >> endurance >> id) {
           // Set up the player object.
           player = Player(name, classType, strength, endurance, id);
       }
       else {
           // Error when reading player characteristics from line.
           // Need to set the errror state of the stream.
           str.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
       }
    }
    return str;
}

std::vector<Player> getPlayers() {
    std::ifstream                 playerFile("Player.txt");
    std::istream_iterator<Player> playerIter(playerFile);
    std::istream_iterator<Player> end;

    return std::vector<Player>(playerIter, end);
}
#endif
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include "DEPENDENCIES.h"

int main() {

std::vector<Player> allPlayers(getPlayers());
//Do whatever with the vector here

return 0;
}
```

## Errors as promised

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/iterator:66:0,
                 from main.cpp:18:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stream_iterator.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_iterator() [with _Tp = Player; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Dist = long int]':
DEPENDENCIES.h:79:35:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stream_iterator.h:65:46: error: no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'
       : _M_stream(0), _M_value(), _M_ok(false) {}
                                              ^
In file included from main.cpp:21:0:
DEPENDENCIES.h:23:3: note: candidate: Player::Player(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int, int, int)
   Player(std::string inpName, std::string inpClassType, int inpStrength, int inpEndurance, int inpId) {
   ^~~~~~
DEPENDENCIES.h:23:3: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 0 provided
DEPENDENCIES.h:11:7: note: candidate: Player::Player(const Player&)
 class Player {
       ^~~~~~
DEPENDENCIES.h:11:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
DEPENDENCIES.h:11:7: note: candidate: Player::Player(Player&&)
DEPENDENCIES.h:11:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/iterator:66:0,
                 from main.cpp:18:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stream_iterator.h: In instantiation of 'std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_iterator(std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_type&) [with _Tp = Player; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Dist = long int; std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]':
DEPENDENCIES.h:78:56:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stream_iterator.h:69:40: error: no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'
       : _M_stream(std::__addressof(__s))
                                        ^
In file included from main.cpp:21:0:
DEPENDENCIES.h:23:3: note: candidate: Player::Player(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int, int, int)
   Player(std::string inpName, std::string inpClassType, int inpStrength, int inpEndurance, int inpId) {
   ^~~~~~
DEPENDENCIES.h:23:3: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 0 provided
DEPENDENCIES.h:11:7: note: candidate: Player::Player(const Player&)
 class Player {
       ^~~~~~
DEPENDENCIES.h:11:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
DEPENDENCIES.h:11:7: note: candidate: Player::Player(Player&&)
DEPENDENCIES.h:11:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

exit status 1
```

Comment: What is the problem you have with the code you show? What is your question?

Comment: So what's the issue you are having? What outcome do you expect, what do you observe, and how do the two differ? You seem to have forgotten to actually ask a question.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to copy-paste the actual errors.

Comment: Jeez I must be forgetting everything today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crucial part of the error messages is this:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'
> ```

If we read e.g. [this `std::istream_iterator` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) we will see

> `T` must meet the [`DefaultConstructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible), [...] requirements.

Since your `Player` class don't have a default constructor you can't use it together with `std::istream_iterator`.

The simple solution is of course to create a default constructor. It can even be as simple as

```
Player() = default;
```